# Using A Barcode Scanner Alongside AppleScripts

Tags: automation, applescript

I want the program to wait on the user to scan a barcode, take the text inputed by the barcode scanner, and then drop that code into a Google Form.

Good day,

I am familiar with Apple Scripts and have used it before to automate tasks, but I am trying to emplement it into a more specific task. My plan is to have it open up a Google Form in Safari. And then wait for the user to scan a barcode, then take that input text from the barcode and drop it into a spot on the Google Form. Any help would be appreciative of any help for being able to have the program wait on teh barcode input, then continue on with the script! Thank you!

Here is an example Google Form to go along with what the following code will be doing: https://forms.gle/E4SGL7jPqaHsf5Cb9

(Please note, in the code below, the repeats are commented out because they will eventually be used, but not during testing.)

Code:

```
    --repeat--

    tell application "Safari"

        activate

        make new document

    end tell


    tell application "System Events"

        tell application process "Safari"

            keystroke "https://forms.gle/isxQK1xjkow8xiUq8"

            keystroke return

        delay 2

        keystroke tab

        -- This is where the code would need to be added for inputing the text from the barcode scanner --

        keystroke tab

        keystroke return

        end tell

        end tell


        tell application "Safari"

        close window 1

        end tell

    --end repeat--
```

Comment: So, what were you planning to use to read the barcodes?

Comment: I'm planning on using just a normal USB barcode scanner

Comment: AppleScript doesn't know anything about barcode scanners, so how are you going to use it?  What application are you going to use, and does it have a scripting dictionary?

Comment: The barcode scanner will input text, so I need the script to wait on text input from the user and then drop the text into the Google Form

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document
    tell the front document
        set the URL to "https://forms.gle/isxQK1xjkow8xiUq8"
        repeat until source ≠ "" -- wait for web page to fully load
            delay 0.5
        end repeat

        repeat -- wait until Key Card Code input field is not empty
            try
                if ["", current application] does not contain ¬
                    (do JavaScript "document
                    .querySelector('input.exportInput')
                    .dataset['initialValue'];") then ¬
                    exit repeat
            end try
            delay 1
        end repeat

        -- Click the Submit button
        do JavaScript "document.querySelector('div.quantumWizButtonEl')
                               .click();"
    end tell
end tell
```

---

What also might be noteworthy and useful to you is that I believe the *Key Card Code* can be submitted via a query parameter in the following URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSftqU8ZKpiw-JNwD_IF2LQ5of2rvZwT9kWUTEm2pH_YEX4rwg/formResponse?fvv=1&entry.240624510={{Key-Card-Code}}
```

where `{{Key-Card-Code}}` is to be substituted with the input.  It might provide an alternative means of automating form submissions.